# Looking for an example to vividly illustrate that tail-recursive calls take less space than non-tail-recursive?

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, f#, tail-recursion, biginsight-examples

Software developers in functional programming languages have been told that tail-recursive calls are better than non-tail-recursive ones. A classic example in textbooks is the tail-recursive factorial function (written in F#)

```
let rec faci n r = 
  if n = 0 then r else faci (n-1) (r * n)
```

versus its non-tail-recursive counter-part.

```
let rec facr n = 
  if n = 0 then 1 else n * facr(n-1)
```

It is relatively clear that `faci` above does not need an extra stack frame when calling itself as `facr` would do. But I am looking for a more vivid example, preferable in F#, from which one can *demonstrate* why tail-recursive-functions are better than non-tail-recursive ones. Ideally, the improvement can be visualized, *e.g.*, with a memory profiler, or by printing some debugging info. Any idea about such an example?

Comment: Tail recursion depends on an accumulator. If the accumulator is just a single, computed value like in your example, tail recursion requires less memory. However, if it accumulates the result of each recursive step without information loss (in a list, for instance), you essentially trade call stack for heap. It might still be more memory efficient, though.

Comment: Good to know this. Thanks!

Comment: tbh, this might not be as straightforward as you think. Some tailcalls will be optimized away into a loop by the compiler for example. Recursive functions are only better if they are tail recursive, otherwise they will eat you stack for lunch.

Comment: I'd agree with the above, I would demonstrate it by demonstrating factorial using a loop (in C#), and then factorial recursively.